# Appropriate Regression

Tags: logistic, random-effects-model

I am currently working with a data set looking at a binary outcome for a particular disease process. The data was collected at the household level so some households report multiple household members with this disease. Thus, my data is currently in the long format. One assumption is that household wealth predicts outcome thus their is some dependency between individuals. My plan was to run a regression model that looks something like this: logit outcome age gender wealth_score. However, I assume that a random-effects model may be more appropriate since some individuals belong to the same household and the wealth_score is at the household level. Am I on the right track? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. A random effects model for the household level effect seems the only legitimate modeling approach. As far as the selection of (fixed) adjustment effects, I'm not sure what is appropriate to the specific question, but you should perhaps account for other design principals (stratification factors, predictors of non-response, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the input